# Add more structure tag to permalink?

Tags: permalinks

I'm new in wordpress .I wondering is there anyway to get the category id in permalink ?
My current permalink is :

```
http:///example.com/%category%/%post_id%-%postname%.html
http:///example.com/music/1-hello.html
```

Now my music category_id is 2 , how to add this category_id to permalink ?  I want to this:

```
http:///example.com/2-music/1-hello.html
```

Answer (score 0):

=> Create a Custom Taxonomy

First, we create a custom taxonomy object called rating with the `register_taxonomy` WordPress function.

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_rating_init' );

function my_rating_init() {
    if ( ! is_taxonomy( 'rating' ) ) {
        register_taxonomy( 
            'rating', 
            'post', 
            array( 
                'hierarchical' => FALSE, 
                'label' => __( 'Rating' ),  
                'public' => TRUE, 
                'show_ui' => TRUE,
                'query_var' => 'rating',
                'rewrite' => true 
            ) 
        );
    }
}
```

Setting `'rewrite' => true` will automatically add the tag `%rating%` to our WordPress system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to add the category ID to your permalink in WordPress. You can use the following code in your `functions.php` file to add the category ID to your permalink structure:

```
function add_category_id_to_permalink( $post_link, $post ) {
    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'post' ) {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );
        if( $terms ) {
            return str_replace( '%category%', $terms[0]->term_id . '-' . $terms[0]->slug, $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_link', 'add_category_id_to_permalink', 10, 2 );
```

This code will add the first category's ID and slug to the permalink structure. Just make sure to update your permalink structure in WordPress settings to include `%category%` before adding this code.